# ProgressDialog before loading a video in Titanium

Tags: android, video, titanium, activity-indicator

I am working at an `Android` app in `Titanium`. At a certain screen I must play a video from a link. It takes some time for charging so I must put a `ProgressDialog` until the video starts. I tried to use `ActivityIndicator` for this, like this :

```
var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
        backgroundColor:'#000',
        fullscreen:true
   });

   var dialog = Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator();
    dialog.message = 'Loading...';

   win.add(dialog);
   dialog.show(); 

   activeMovie.setUrl(url);
   activeMovie.mediaControlStyle=Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_FULLSCREEN;

   activeMovie.addEventListener("preload", function(e){
        dialog.show()  ;        
  });

   activeMovie.addEventListener('load', function(e){
        dialog.hide()  ;        
   });
   activeMovie.addEventListener('complete', function(e){
        activeMovie.stop();
        navController.close();
   });
```

This code make appear the `ProgressDialog` for 2 seconds and then disappear. After this time I get a black screen for a time (the video is charging) and after this time video starts. Can anyone help me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to your problem might be :

```
var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
       url: url,
       backgroundColor:'#111',
       movieControlMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT // See TIMOB-2802, which may change this property name

    });

    win.add(activeMovie);
    var dlg = Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator();
    win.addEventListener('open',function()
    {
           dlg.setMessage('Loading...');
           dlg.show();
    });

    activeMovie.addEventListener('load',function()
    {
           dlg.hide();
    });

    activeMovie.addEventListener('complete',function()
    {
           win.close();
    });

    activeMovie.play();

    win.addEventListener('close', function() 
    {
           windowClosed = true;
           activeMovie.stop();
    });
```